# JTable in JScrollPane not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, scrollpane

I have this code to create a `JTable` in my panel and I don't know where is the problem.

```
public void View()//method to store our view Scroll Pane
    {

        pnlView = new JPanel();
        pnlView.setSize(500,500);
        pnlView.setLayout(null);


        btnVBack = new JButton();
        btnVBack.setBounds(260,180,150,30);
        btnVBack.setText("BACK");
        btnVBack.addActionListener(this);
        pnlView.add(btnVBack);
        pnlView.setVisible(true);
        this.add(pnlView);



    }
```

So I try to add this code to add a `JTable` to my panel:

```
    public void View()
    {

        pnlView = new JPanel();
        pnlView.setSize(500,500);
        pnlView.setLayout(null);

        btnVBack = new JButton();
            btnVBack.setBounds(260,180,150,30);
        btnVBack.setText("BACK");
        btnVBack.addActionListener(this);
        pnlView.add(btnVBack);

        String[] columnNames = {"first name","last name","address"};
        Object[][]data = {{"John","Kane","NY"},{"Nayomi","Writz","NY"}};
        JTable table =  new JTable(data, columnNames);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       getContentPane().add(panel);

        pnlView.add(scrollPane);

        pnlView.setVisible(true);
        this.add(pnlView);
}
```

Nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use a null layout!!! Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.
2. Don't add the TableHeader to a panel.
3. You are adding the scrollPane to two different components. It should only be added to one.
4. Panels are visible by default. You don't need pnlView.setVisible(true)
5. Why are you creating the "panel" variable and adding an empty panel to the frame?

Read the JTable API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables` for working examples. Start with working code. The tutorials also show you how to better structure your code by using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...).

Comment: I added the **ScrollPanel** to the jframe **this.add(scrollPane);** and didn't work too. here i have two panels in the **JFrame**. **pnlView** for the Button and **ScroolPane** for the **Jtable**

Comment: @Alaeddine, did you read the tutorial and download the example code to see how it works? Post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) if you need more help.

Comment: I used this Demo. Also didn't find a Solution [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components/SimpleTableDemo.java)

Comment: I made an Edit in my question would you please Check it?

Comment: @Alaeddine, what do you mean you didn't find a solution? Does the demo work? All the demo does is add the scrollPane to the panel. Then the panel is added to the frame. I don't know how to make it any simpler than that. Since you haven't listened to any of my suggestions (you are still using a null layout) and you haven't posted a proper `SSCCE`, I can't help.

Comment: I know your answer is Right but I couldn't implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the Solution :

```
public void View()//method to store our view Scroll Pane
    {

        pnlView = new JPanel();
        pnlView.setSize(500,500);



        btnVBack = new JButton();
        btnVBack.setBounds(340,180,150,30);
        btnVBack.setText("BACK");
        btnVBack.addActionListener(this);
        pnlView.add(btnVBack);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 330, 300);
        add(scrollPane);
        String columnNames[] = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };

        // Create some data
        String dataValues[][] =
        {
            { "12", "234", "67" },
            { "-123", "43", "853" },
            { "93", "89.2", "109" },
            { "279", "9033", "3092" }
        };
        table = new JTable(dataValues, columnNames);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);


        pnlView.setVisible(true);
        this.add(pnlView);



    }//view
```

Comment: That is not the solution. Don't use a null layout!!! How many times do I need to repeat that. The reason you had so many problems is because you are using a null layout. Read the tutorial and learn how to use layout managers and solve you problem properly!